# Colored Text in PostScript Files

Tags: formatting, color, postscript

I am using `\textcolor` command in the body of my TeX file. I need to generate Postscript file.

When I go through the `"Option Menu\Configure TeXStudio\Build\PDF chain"`, every thing is fine and I can get the colored text as I have planed in the .tex file. However, when I go through the `"Option Menu\Configure TeXStudio\Build\PS chain"`, I get undefined control sequence error for `\textcolor` command. It seems `\textcolor` command is unknown when I am trying to generate PS output.

Is there anyway so I can fix the problem? Perhaps, using an alternative command to change the text color or an alternative way to generate PS file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX. Can you make a small example that replicates the problem such that people can check whether it is a code issue or TeXStudio related?

Comment: Does your document contains `\usepackage{color}` or `\usepackage{xcolor}`?

Comment: I have used \xcolor package. It works fine for generating PDF output (no error). However, when I set it to generate PS output, I get error specifically on \textcolor or \color command!

Comment: The same error when using \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}. I guess something is wrong with PS generating method. How can you generate PS output from a .tex file?

Comment: It is a very long code (a long article). Here is one part of the code: \textcolor{blue}{...a sample text...}. It is IEEE Transaction file. The complete file is found at: http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html

Comment: @frank: In order for the community to help you, please put in the effort to help us. Strip down your "long article" into a core that replicates the problem. This is what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Many people have resolved their problem via this approach (sometimes by themselves).

Comment: Did you really compile with LaTeX, not pdfLaTeX? The `dvipsnames`  option  has nothing to do with with the compiler: it's just a list of all colors known to dvips.

Comment: I got the issue resolved. It was really funny. I had the following command in the beginning of the document: \ifCLASSINFOpdf and then \usepackage{color}. After I moved \usepackage{color} before the \ifCLASSINFOpdf, the issue was resolved. Thanks.

Comment: coding error (package not loaded)